# is there way to create box for info or to be title in admin panel in django

Tags: django, django-admin

is there way to create box for info or to be title in admin panel in django like photo

for example when i add new record i want put box for info

[image]

my admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog_app.models import Android
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Android)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the info box will just contain something static (unchanging), then you can just customize the admin templates, as explained in the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial07/#customize-the-admin-look-and-feel). For example:

1. In the root directory of your project (next to `manage.py`), create a `templates` directory. Inside that, create another folder, `admin`.
2. Copy `base.html` [(link)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) to admin, so you'll have `templates/admin/base.html`.
3. Edit `base.html` and add the following just before the line `<!-- Content -->`:

   `<div style="padding: 1em 3em; background: #aea;">This is a custom info box.</div>`
4. Run Django and open your admin site. It will look like this:

[image]

However you mentioned “when i add new record i want put box for info”, so you might want to do something dynamic. Note however that the Django admin already uses the [Django `messages` framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/) to do that kind of thing. You probably should just customize that, though the steps to do it are more involved.